# Adding SQL Server ID Increment upon registration

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How would I retrieve an Id from my SQL Server table, add +1 to it, and register that number to the next Id when someone registers into my program?

This is my code so far. The `??` means I don't know what would go there for this to work.

```
SqlCommand hi = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Table");
hi.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
hi.Connection = connection;
hi.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ??);
```

For example, last Id was 14. Now someone is registering and I want it to say 15 in the SQL Server table under Id.

Comment: Why don't you just make your ID column an [auto increment column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your full table structure is like, but the functionality you're describing is available natively in a SQL Server databases, and it's called an **identity** column. The way you would implement it is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Id int not null identity(1,1),
    Name nvarchar(255) not null
    # other columns go here...
)
```

You should be able to alter an existing table to make an Id column use identity, the only catch is you can only have one identity column per table.

When you want to insert a new record into the table, you can leave the identity column out of your insert statement, as SQL Server will fill it with the appropriate value:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name) 
VALUES ('My Name')
```

Comment: [Id]  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -- Gives me error "Incorrect syntax near 'unsigned'

Comment: It shouldn't... are you sure you are using MySQL and not Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server lol. Oh crap!! EDIT, huge mistake with the tags!

Comment: Ah, well that changes the answer entirely... you should probably change the tag on the question then.

Comment: Done. I just realized why are people talking about mysql. Lol.

Comment: Well, luckily the syntax is very similar between mysql and sql server...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to handle it at database level by making ID column auto increment.
If you want to do it from your code then you have to make additional hit to database to get last ID before you make your insert call to add data.